# Formatting USB Drive for an embedded Linux device using an Windows PC

Tags: windows, embedded, usb-drive

Is there a way to partition / format a USB drive for use with an Embedded Linux device running Ubuntu 16.04.07 on a Windows 10 PC?

It worked several months ago using the standard Windows format dialog as FAT32, but since several weeks it doesn't. If i format the USB drive and plug it into the Linux system it looks like there is no partition on the USB drive.

If i take a look on ls /dev, there is only the main device sda, but no partition like sda1.

If i use fdisk and mkfs it works, but in this case i have only access to a damn Windows PC.

Answer (score 0):

It is not absolutely necessary to have partitions on a USB drive: creating a filesystem on the whole-disk device is sometimes called a "superfloppy" configuration, as classic 5.25" and 3.5" floppy disks were used without partitioning.

However, you could use Windows Disk Management to partition the device, and then format the resulting partition.